# Good operating system/virtualization layer combination for running dual screen with XP in a vm instance?

Tags: windows, linux, vmware, virtualbox, java

I have a situation where my work computer has Outlook+Lotus Notes with draconian protection.  Unfortunately this means that Eclipse development (meaning zillions of small files) gets very slow.

I now have a situation where I have been allowed to migrate the Outlook+Notes stuff in a virtual machine so the rest of the host OS can be used for development at a more leisurely protection level.

I have good experience with vmware workstation under XP and vmware Fusion, some with VirtualBox (the latest had network issues under OS X).

I was expecting either to put OpenSolaris (for dtracing java, no a Mac is not an option) or Ubuntu as the host OS.

My primary wish is to have both host and guest being able to use the laptop + external screen as effortless as in native XP, hence the need to ask for experiences :)

Does anybody have good or bad experiences to tell?  Please make an answer pr vm/os combination to allow for acceptance when I've decided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) to do this, and allow it to operate in seamless mode.

[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) is a nice **cross-platform**, *free* application which allows you to do this.  You can emulate nearly every operating system under one-another.  The full list of compatible guest operating systems can be found [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes).

The following is Mac OS X emulating Windows XP in seamless mode:

[image: VirtualBox Seamless Mode Example]

You could essentially have the two taskbars running with eachother, and move applications to and from monitors as you please.  You might want to see [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1060977) on the Ubuntu Forums for more information, or [this section in the VirtualBox manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#advanced-multimonitor).

Comment: Unfortunately, OS X does not run well on my Dell laptop.  I am aware that VirtualBox is freely available, but I have had networking issues on the latest version on my Mac, so I am a bit careful and would like to hear _experiences_ from others.

Comment: You said that you wanted to use Ubuntu, however, as the host operating system... That screenshot is just an example, it's very possible with other operating systems as well:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9c/Virtualbox15seamless.png/750px-Virtualbox15seamless.png

Comment: VirtualBox is available for Linux and Windows, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Windows + VirtualBox. If you have multiple monitors you can install XP in a VM, install guest additions, then you can let the VM have an entire monitor and it will be more or less seamless. I personally didn't have a good experience with the "seamless mode", but maybe that's just because i was using Win7 64 Bit.